# Automate Google 2FA authentication from bash script for copying files with rsync

Tags: ubuntu, bash, rsync, jenkins

An automated bash script to generate OTP (verification codes) from Google's 2FA secret key and generated OTP (verification codes) should use for transfer data from one Ubuntu server to another 2FA enabled Ubuntu server

I use `rsync` command to transfer files from my Jenkins server to production server. Production server is enabled with 2FA. I need to automate this process without using any other resources like AWS S3.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sshpass` and `oathtool` together for copying files to 2FA enabled servers. So we can remove [nullok](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam#nullok) from server and tighten up server against brute force attack.

**Prerequisites:**

Source / Jenkins server:

1. sudo apt install sshpass
2. sudo apt install oathtool

Destination server:

1. create a SSH key and 2FA authentication file in user's home.

Jenkins server:

Following is the example of copying files from Jenkins to 2FA enabled server:

```
sshpass -p `oathtool -b  --totp 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'` rsync -aruvhze 'ssh -i /var/lib/jenkins/ssh_key.txt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --progress /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/* scp_user@10.10.10.46:/opt/build/
```

- 2FA secret key xxxxxxxxxxxxx
- SSH key file /var/lib/jenkins/ssh_key.txt
- Source folder: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build/*
- Destination server user: scp_user
- Destination server: 10.10.10.46
- Destination: /opt/build/